viewPager inside a fragment (kotlin and xml)
I want to add ViewPager inside a fragment so that it allows you to create a swipeable views structure within that fragment
so i have bottom navigation bar that swapes between 3 fragments
1 fragment i want it to have swipeable cardViews (cardview has a title, botton and an imageView)
how do i do that ?
